# Extract digit from numeric in r

Tags: r, decimal, extract

I would like to extract the first digit after a decimal place from a numeric vector in R. Is there a way to do this without turning it into a character string? For example:

```
x <- c(1.0,1.1,1.2)
```

I would like the function to return a vector:

```
 0,1,2
```

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There'll be a bunch of ways, but here's one:

```
(x %% 1)*10
# [1] 0 1 2
```

This assumes there's only ever one digit after the decimal place. If that's not the case:

```
floor((x %% 1)*10)
```

Comment: I had `floor((x - floor(x))*10)` before you edited.  Won't bother now.