# Drop part of an integer in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, which includes the year and the month combined to form a single integer.

Example dataset:

```
dataset = c(201601, 201602, 201603, 201604,201605,201606,201607,201608,201609,201610, 201611 ,201612 )
```

I want to extract only the month part from each record in R. 
The expected output is:

```
dataset_months = c(01, 02, 03, 04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12 )
```

How do I perform this?

Comment: duplicate  question and a very generic too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected output seem to be a string, I would suggest you will stay in the integer world for efficiency and convenience, something like (the idea's taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868744/3001626))

```
((dataset / 100) %% 1) * 100 
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
## OR just `dataset - 201600` ?
```

You could also easily achieve this using `substring` (if you want a `character` vector in return)

```
substring(dataset, 5)
# [1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

Or you could do a date manipulation

```
as.POSIXlt(paste0(as.character(dataset), "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")$mon + 1L
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `substr`

```
substr(dataset, nchar(dataset)-1, nchar(dataset))
#[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```

or with `sub`

```
sub(".{4}", "", dataset)
```

---

Or an option using `Date` manipulation

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(as.character(dataset), "%Y%m"), "%m")
#[1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12"
```