# Extract first digit from each element of a numeric vector in R

Tags: r

A little bit like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868712/extract-digit-from-numeric-in-r), I would like to extract the first digit from each element of a numeric vector, without having it to turn into a character vector and back.

```
d <- c(123, 2, 45)
```

Expected Output:

```
[1] 1 2 4
```

I tried different stuff with `floor()`, but without the desired result.

Comment: `as.numeric(substr(d, 1, 1))` ... ok, the undesired coercion is done implicit. without using character: `d %/% 10^as.integer(log10(d))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One numerical approach here would be to divide each input number by 10 raised to the floor of log base 10.  This means that, for example, we divide an input of `123` by `100`, to yield `1.23`.  Then, we take the floor of that to yield the first digit `1`.

```
getFirstDigit <- function(x) {
    floor(x / (10 ^ floor(log10(x))))
}

d <- c(123, 2, 45)
getFirstDigit(d)

[1] 1 2 4
```

The more brute force way of doing this would be to cast the input vector to character, take the first character, and then cast back to a number.  But, I doubt doing it that way would outperform what I have above.

Comment: @jogo You know what, you're right `:-)` ... by the way, I have seen this question come up in many different languages on this site, most recently in Python.