# Finding specific decimal point digit

Tags: r

For example, if I had the number 7.12935239484 and wanted just the 10th decimal place digit (in this example the answer would be 8), how would I go about displaying that using R?

Comment: I think this is not really an exact duplicate (the linked dupe is "how do I extract the *first* digit after the decimal place?". You could argue that it's a trivial extension, but I'm not sure it would be trivial to new programmers ... (not practically important since it's been answered ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple by 1e10, convert to an integer, and then perform mod 10 to retrieve the number.

```
floor(7.12935239484* 1e10)  %%10
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably by string manipulation.

- Use `format()` with enough digits to make sure that you include the digits you want.
- I have written the digit position as `10+2` to emphasize that you are skipping over the first two digits (`7.`) and taking the 10th digit after the decimal point.

```r
x <- 7.12935239484
substr(format(x,digits=20), start = 10+2, stop = 10+2)
```

It might be more principled (and robust) to use numerical manipulation

```r
floor((x*1e10) %% 10)
```

This shifts the decimal point 10 places and then calculates the reminder modulo 10 (the parentheses around `x*1e10` are needed to get the right order of operations). This would still work if there were more digits to the left of the decimal point (unlike the string-based solution).

[Extract digit from numeric in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868712/extract-digit-from-numeric-in-r) is almost a duplicate ...